# How can I multiply an nxn matrix A in fortran x times to get its power without amplifying rounding errors?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, numerical-methods, numerical-stability

How can I multiply an NxN matrix A in Fortran x times to get its power without amplifying rounding errors?

Comment: How precise does your computation needs to be? Have you tried using 64, 128 bit floating point numbers? It would be great if you could show a test case with results and expectations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A can be diagonalized as

`A P = P D`,

where `P` is some NxN matrix (each column is called 'eigenvector'),  and `D` is an NxN diagonal matrix (the diagonal elements are called 'eigenvalues'), then

`A = P D P^{-1}`,

where `P^{-1}` is the inverse matrix of `P`. Therefore the second power of `A` results in

`A A= P D P^{-1} P D P^{-1} = P D D P^{-1}`.

Repeating multiplication of `A` for `x` times yields

`A^x = P D^x P^{-1}`.

Note here that `D^x` is still a diagonal matrix. Let the `i`-th diagonal element of `D` be `D_{ii}`. Then, the `i`-th diagonal element of `D^x` is

`[D^x]_{ii} = (D_{ii})^x`.

That is, the elements of `D^x` is simply `x`-th power of the elements of `D` and can be computed without much rounding error, I guess. Now, you multiply `P` and `P^{-1}` from left and right, respectively, to this `D^x` to obtain `A^x`. The error in `A^x` depends on the error of `P` and `P^{-1}`, which can be calculated by some subroutines in numerical packages such as LAPACK.

Answer (score 2):

as alluded to in the answer by norio, one can employ in general the Jordan (or alternatively Schur) decomposition and proceed in a similar fashion - for details (including brief error analysis) see, e.g., Chapter 11 of Matrix computations by Golub and Loan.